# how to solve "Uncaught TagError: adsbygoogle.push() error: All ins elements in the DOM with class=adsbygoogle already have ads in them." error

Tags: reactjs, adsense

am using google adsense on my react app and I implemented the code for ad-unit component as follows:

```
export const SideAdPlaceholder = () => {
  (window.adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
  return (
    <div
      className="adSides"
    >
      <ins
        className="adsbygoogle"
        style={{ display: "block" }}
        data-ad-client="ca-<adsense account>"
        data-ad-slot="32777475897"
        data-ad-format="auto"
        data-full-width-responsive="true"
      ></ins>
    </div>
  );
};
```

and added `<script  type="text/plain" data-cookiescript="accepted"  async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js?client=ca-<adsense account>" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>`  inside the body of the **index.html** file. But I received the following error

[image]

can anyone tell me how to solve this error

Comment: Same error. A solution would be amazing!

Answer (score 2):

I believe I have found the solution, ReactStrict Mode causes components to render twice. Thus on the first render it inserts an ad into the ins tag and then on the second attempt its already full.

Solution - Remove React.StrictMode from `index.js`

Replace:

```
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App/>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

With:

```
root.render(
  <App/>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

adsByGoogle has a property named "loaded" which is true when the ads are already loaded in the  element. To resolve the issue a quick check for the loaded property before pushing would resolve the issue.

It worked by my nextjs app.

```js
if (adsbygoogle && !adsbygoogle.loaded)
      (adsbygoogle = (window as any).adsbygoogle || []).push({});
```